# Issue with `document.write` clearing the page after a setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the number of UL (IL) elements (with a delay) on my website.

This is the function I use (listednumber.js);

```
setTimeout(function() { 
document.write($("#myUL li").length);
}, 5000);
```

The HTML:

```
<i class="fas fa-archive"></i> <a href="listed.html"> Listed :</a> <b><script type="text/javascript" src="./js/listednumber.js"></script></b>
```

When the timer goes to 0 it executes and displays the correct number but, the number get displayed on a new blank web page, instead of the current web page.
When I normally use `document.write` without the timer it the number doesn't get displayed on a new web page but on the current one.

I want to number to be displayed on the current web page.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: You shouldn't use document.write to add things to the webpage in the first place. Look into DOM manipulation, but briefly, you would use `document.getElementById(body).innerHTML = $("#myUL li").length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` is `document.wrong`. Please use something more modern and less prone to doing confusing things. This function tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead.

Select the `<b>` element you want to insert the text into instead:

```
<b id="liCount"></b>
```

listednumber.js:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#liCount').text($("#myUL li").length)
}, 5000);
```